# how to implement multiple advice on target methods using spring aop and store return values in common java object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I know what is advice and how I can call .

We are planning to use spring aop to validate input. Input is java pojo 
 something like below e.g.

```
class Employee {
    int id;
    int age ;
    String name ;
    String designation;
    String address;
}
```

1> I want to know how to validate input called passed to my service methods.

2> I want to do certain validations on that input (please refer above) , ie running certain business rules .

3> I have different rules in different advice and if input passes all store them to db Employee table other wise store all Error table.

4> Advice/Rules could be like 
        NotProperAgeRule : age should be in between 18 and 60.
        NotProperAddressRule : Address zip code must be  10001 , 10002
        NotProperName :  Name can not contain special characters.

5>If the rules fail they should logged to another table.
     like for user id 101 -> name is not proper , no proper age.

6> All these rules should be in their own Advice classes.

7> So they should run in proper **chain** and store all the errors in some kind of List.

I tried to using MethodBeforeAdvice but I can not collect all the errors in single List from all the Advice.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: It will be something how to create chain of aop advice which consolidates all the rules errors into java list. since MethodBeforeAdvice methods will return void. How do I pass java list containing errors to next Advice along with input.? can you give 1 or 2 examples or hint ?

Comment: Why not using javax.validation?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this. We had single advice but we had injected it with a collection of Validators.
Each Validation bean implemented same interface Validate.
Validate has single method doValidation which takes input pojo and list to which errors have to be logged.
Spring will find all such validators and inject into your advice class. All you have to do is loop through all validation list and invoke doValidate. All errors will be logged to same list.

But this will have single advice class, if you still want separate advice then you can create your own bean to hold messages and use it as singleton bean to inject to all advice class. Also take care if threading as all advice will try to add to same collection. To specify order of advices please http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html